# RegWrite not writing to the registry

Tags: autohotkey

```
ValueType := A_Args[1]
KeyName   := A_Args[2]
ValueName := A_Args[3]
ValueData := A_Args[4]
Loop, %0%
    params .= A_Space %A_Index%

; https://autohotkey.com/docs/Run#RunAs
full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")
if !(A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)")) {
    try {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" "%params%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%" "%params%"
    }
    ExitApp
}

RegWrite, % ValueType, % KeyName, % ValueName, % ValueData
```

Why is RegWrite not writing to the registry when I pass parameters to the script?

Comment: Are you sure your script is running as admin? Put this right after `RegWrite` on the next line:
` If ( ErrorLevel ) { MsgBox % A_LastError } else { MsgBox % "No error" } ` and run it. What is A_LastError?

Comment: That returns `87`; I had assumed the UAC prompt meant that I was elevating the script.

Answer (score 0):

[A_LastError codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Code 87 means an invalid parameter. What are you passing to `RegWrite`?

Here's one function I use for debugging. If `isCondition` is true it shows a custom error message and stops everything.

```
fAbort(isCondition, sFuncName, sNote, dVars:="") {
    If isCondition {
        sAbortMessage := % sFuncName ": " sNote
        . "`n`nA_LineNumber: """ A_LineNumber """`nErrorLevel: """ ErrorLevel """`nA_LastError: """ A_LastError """`n"
        For sName, sValue in dVars
            sAbortMessage .= "`n" sName ": """ sValue """"
        MsgBox, 16,, % sAbortMessage
        ExitApp
    }
}
```

After a `RegWrite` it could be used like this:

```
fAbort(ErrorLevel                   ; 1, if RegWrite unsuccessful.
, "Script or function name here"    ; Could use A_ThisFunc for current function name.
, "Registry write unsuccessful."    ; Your custom message here.
, { x: "blabla", y: 13 }            ; Additional vars you want to see in the msgbox.
)
```

Comment: `ValueType := "REG_DWORD"`
`KeyName   := "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome"`
`ValueName := "IncognitoModeAvailability"`
`Run, % "AutoHotkeyU32.exe RegWrite.ahk " ValueType " " KeyName " " ValueName " " 0`

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue.
I made file `one.ahk`:
`a := "REG_DWORD"`
`b := "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome"`
`c := "IncognitoModeAvailability"`
`Run, % "C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkeyU32.exe two.ahk " a " " b " " c " " 0`
And file "two.ahk":
`RegWrite, % A_Args[1], % A_Args[2], % A_Args[3], % A_Args[4]`

And if I run `one.ahk` as administrator it writes successfully to the registry.